# Wordpress website scrolling not working on one page with certain browser size only

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am setting up a new wordpress website, and the header gets stuck and won't scroll on the / page, but no others to my knowledge. On my Macbook Air 11 inch, the default browser screen size makes it get stuck, but other sizes work fine. Tested with Chrome and Safari.

WEBSITE LINK REMOVED - SOLVED

Please advise! Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Header was switching between sticky and fixed with page length.